# Get records from primary table when secondary table is returning null in left join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have two tables (Joined using Left Outer Join) primary table always have data and secondary table may have or many not have data using where clause,

My issue here is when secondary table returns rows then only my query displays some data if secondary table returns **Zero** rows then my query also returns **zero** rows but I am using left join as per my knowledge though secondary table returns **Zero** rows I need to have data from primary table.

```
select * from 
(
    SELECT Flag, [Description1], [group_code], [category_code]
    FROM Item_TMP
) b --Primary table
Left outer join
Base a --Seconday table
    on a.Part_ID = b.category_code
where b.category_code between 'A' and 'F'
AND b.type = 'Goods'
```

I need to have data irrespective of table 2 returns rows.

### Edit

Item_TMP table

```
Flag   [Description1]   [group_code]   [category_code]
WO      Computers        FP               A
SO      LAptops          FP               F
```

Base Table

```
part_id    quantity
 A           50
 F           100
```

Now where Base table may return or may not return

Required Output

If Base table returns data then

```
Flag   [Description1]   [group_code]   [category_code]  Sales
WO      Computers        FP               A              50
SO      LAptops          FP               F             100
```

If Base table doesn't return data

```
Flag   [Description1]   [group_code]   [category_code]  Sales
WO      Computers        FP               A              0
SO      LAptops          FP               F             0
```

Comment: This should not compile - I din't see any column called `Code` in your `b` table...

Comment: @ZoharPeled actually I can't paste the orginal query here, so made some changes but query is compiling but returns zero rows if table returns zero rows, can you please help struck here

Comment: @ZoharPeled actually I need a way to get the records of left table irrespective of right table records

Comment: Zohar's point is @Siva is that you have the column `[category_code]` within your subquery (which you alias `b`, however, outside the query you reference `b.code`; there is no column `code` inside the subquery `b`. This might seem like a small mistake, but if the code you have supplied is clearly wrong, it lowers the trust of the users here have of your example, as it isn't going to compile in the first place.

Comment: @Larnu yes sir accepted I will update the question but how can I get the data can you please help

Comment: @Larnu I have updated the question

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `ISNULL` or `coalesce` function

```
select b.*,coalesce(quantity,0) Sales
from 
(
    SELECT Flag, [Description1], [group_code], [category_code]
    FROM Item_TMP
) b --Primary table
Left join
Base a --Seconday table
    on a.Part_ID = b.category_code
where b.category_code between 'A' and 'F'
AND b.type = 'Goods'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try now

Answer (score 1):

I would write it in a simple left join with isnull()

```
select b.Flag, b.[Description1], b.[group_code], b.[category_code], 
isnull(a.quantity, 0) Sales
FROM Item_TMP b 
    Left join Base a  on a.Part_ID = b.category_code
where b.category_code between 'A' and 'F' 
    AND b.type = 'Goods'
```